# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @org.hibernate.annotations.Table references an unknown table: ProductForPractice

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to work on Hibernate 4.1.4 version feature. and I am using hsqldb 2.3.3 when I am trying to run the code it is giving me unknown table reference.

Here's my table script:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductForPractice (productId INTEGER,prodName char(25),price DECIMAL(5,2),PRIMARY KEY(productId))
```

Entity class

```
@Entity

@Table(appliesTo="ProductForPractice")
public class Product {


    @Id
    @Column

    private int productId;



    @Column(name="prodName")
    private String prodName;
    @Column
    private double price;
    @Version
    private long version;
//getter and setters
```

Here's my config file

```
config.setProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/");
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "SA");
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
config.addAnnotatedClass(Product.class);

config.setProperty("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class,hbm");

ServiceRegistry serivce=new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(config.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
SessionFactory factory=config.buildSessionFactory(serivce);
```

Here's my full stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @org.hibernate.annotations.Table references an unknown table: ProductForPractice
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:933)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3435)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3389)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1341)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1731)
    at Hibernate.configuration.Service.saveProduct(Service.java:28)
    at main.Main1.main(Main1.java:15)
```

Comment: Have you tried attribute "name" instead of "appliesTo"

Comment: Or maybe CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_FOR_PRACTICE and @Table(name="PRODUCT_FOR_PRACTICE"

Comment: yes but it was showing invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Your Table annotation propably is of class org.hibernate.annotations.Table which just adds information to the annotation javax.persistence.Table that you should use instead:

```
@javax.persistence.Table(name="ProductForPractice")
public class Product {
```